# django.urls.reverse() matching URL pattern instead of name

Tags: python, django, cs50

I am coding a Django project for a Wikipedia-like site (CS50W project 1). I have one app inside the project called *encyclopedia*. Inside my `views.py` file for this app, I have a redirect, for which I use the `django.urls.reverse()` function. The link to the documentation for this function can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

Now for the problem: If the user visits `/wiki/file` where file is not a valid page, then the markdown file will not be found in the `entry` view. And, as you can see, it is supposed to redirect you to the *not found* page. However, the code `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notfound"))` loops the user back to the `entry` view indefinitely, instead of the user being redirected to the *not found* page.

I have found two solutions so far:
One can reorder the URL patterns so that the *notfound* pattern appears before the *entry* pattern, or a slash can be added to either of the aforementioned URL patterns.

I am, however, looking for the cause of the problem. I am currently considering the possibility that the `reverse()` function is using the URL pattern instead of the name for some reason.

`urls.py` file for *encyclopedia*:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("wiki/notfound", views.notfound, name="notfound"),
]
```

`views.py` file for *encyclopedia*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import markdown2
from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def entry(request, title):
    md = util.get_entry(title)

    if md is None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notfound"))
    else:
        html = markdown2.markdown(md)

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "title": title,
        "entry": html
    })

def notfound(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/notfound.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the answer to my question. It is not a caveat in the implementation of `reverse()`. It is merely an interesting outcome due to the way the code works. `reverse()` finds the URL pattern with the name *notfound* and returns it as `/wiki/notfound`. Then `HttpResponseRedirect()` redirects the user to that URL, which just so happens to appear as a URL for the *entry* view first, redirecting the user back to the *entry* view and restarting the process. The *not found* page will never be reached, because its URL is a subset of the URLs for the *entry* view which is above it.